# Parameterization in Junit using constructors

Tags: java, junit, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to do Parameterization in Junit but in my case its giving me errors.
Here is the code that i got in a online tutorial.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
@RunWith (Parameterized.class)
public class parametrization {


    public String username;
    public String password;
    public int pincode;


    public parametrization (String username, String password, int pincode){
        this.username=username;
        this.password=password;
        this.pincode=pincode;
    }

@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> getdata(){
    Object[][] data = new Object[2][3];  
    //row 1st
    data [0][0] = "usernamea";
    data [0][1] = "passa";
    data [0][2] = "111";

    //row 2nd
    data [1][0] = "usernameb";
    data [1][1] = "passb";
    data [1][2] = "222";

    return Arrays.asList(data);
    }


    @Test
    public void testlogin()
        {
        System.out.println(username + "--" + password + "--" + pincode);
        }
}
```

On execution of the above code, i got errors like

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.Parameterized$TestClassRunnerForParameters.createTestUsingConstructorInjection(Parameterized.java:186)
    at org.junit.runners.Parameterized$TestClassRunnerForParameters.createTest(Parameterized.java:181)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:244)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:241)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Is there something that m missing??

Comment: Sorry, this makes no sense to me.  What are you trying to accomplish?  It seems like it's an easy problem that you've made difficult by introducing unnecessary complexity.  Is this just a simplified example of what you really want to do?

Comment: Yes i am new to this. So started with simple code.

Comment: No, that's not simple.

Comment: So what should be a simple way for parametrization in junit + webdriver ?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You issue is that the 3rd argument is an `int` and you are passing a `String`

```
public parametrization (String username, String password, int pincode){
    this.username=username;
    this.password=password;
    this.pincode=pincode;
}
```

Change this

```
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> getdata(){
    Object[][] data = new Object[2][3];  
    //row 1st
    data [0][0] = "usernamea";
    data [0][1] = "passa";
    data [0][2] = "111";
```

to this

```
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> getdata(){
    Object[][] data = new Object[2][3];  
    //row 1st
    data [0][0] = "usernamea";
    data [0][1] = "passa";
    data [0][2] = new Integer(111);
```

Answer (score 0):

or else you could simple remove the double qoutes ("")of int and it should work fine.

@Parameters
    public static collection getData(){

```
    Object obj[][] = new Object[4][3];

    obj[0][0] = "Kevin";
    obj[0][1] = "Anderson";
    obj[0][2] = 270123;
```